# Definite integral of exponential of nested function

Tags: definite-integrals

I struggle to solve the following definite integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-a}^{a} e^{\frac{1}{c_0+c_1\cdot cos(x)}} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

where $c_0\neq 0$, $c_1\neq 0$ and $a > 0$

The substitution approach to a linear expression in the exponential doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Numerical integration is not an option, as the result needs to be calculated dynamically on low power hardware.

Is there a closed form solution to this problem? If not, what would be your suggestion for an approximation?

Thanks for any comments,

Peter